# Mapping classic asp pages to .net in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, wildcard-mapping

I'm trying to map requests for classic asp pages to be handled by .net, so that it runs through a custom httpmodule.

In IIS I have remapped asp requests to aspnet_isapi.dll - I'm sure I've done this bit right

Now in my test app I am getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/TestASPRedirect' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This type of page is not served. 
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /testaspredirect/test.asp
```

Searching online for this error shows a load of people having problems with cassini, but this is not really relevant, I am testing this on both IIS 5.1 on XP dev machine, and have tested on IIS6 also getting the same error.

I have followed instructions for adding and registering a httphandler (see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q308001), but I don't know what to put in the ProcessRequest routine to ensure the request gets passed on. What is the default .net httphandler, can I just map to this in web.config?: so something like:

```
<httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.asp" type="standard.nethttphandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

How do I tell asp.net that it needs to pass ASP requests on and not block?

Comment: I am having the same problem but I am using the built-in Cassini web server. I have a ASP.NET 2.0 web site (not web app) where the home page and other pages are classic ASP. I do NOT have any entry in my v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config that maps *.asp to the forbidden handler. Should I open a new thread or is this comment enough to get some help?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are only one step far from the success. Adding following section to your Local website(or virtual directory) web.config file:

```
<configuration>
...
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".asp" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*.asp" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" validate="true"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Hey, this worked for me testing my Framework 4.5 application under IIS Express, but when moving to production server, it fails... Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `.asp` extension is mapped to the [`HttpForbiddenHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404282(VS.80).aspx).

If you're using ASP.NET 1.1 then open the following file:

> `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\CONFIG\machine.config`

If you're using ASP.NET 2.0 then open this file:

> `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config`

Search for "`path="*.asp"`", then comment out that line. It'll like something like:

```
<!-- machine.config/ASP.NET 1.1-->
<add path="*.asp" verb="*" 
     type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler"/>`

<!-- web.config/ASP.NET 2.0-->
<add path="*.asp" verb="*" 
     type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" validate="true"/>`
```

Comment: thanks for the answer: using 2.0/ in web.config/ no entry for .asp, (must have been caught by the wildcard entry). Added a line for .asp, tried different Handler types: with DefaultHttpHandler get the same error, StaticFileHandler tries to download the asp page to the browser, .UI.PageHandlerFactory throws this error:
    There is no build provider registered for the extension '.asp'. You can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> section....
Have to leave this now but will come back to later to see if any way to get this to work. Maybe it doesn't make logical sense to try this

Comment: @Kev - I have same problem with slightly different environment (please see my comment under the original problem entry). I suspect I should open new thread but not sure...

Comment: @John - seeing as your problem is specific to cassini server I'd open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the below file:

`C:\WINDOWS\MICROSOFT.NET\FRAMEWORK\<FramworkVersion>\Config\web.config`

where `<FramworkVersion>` is folder  name:

open it in an XML editor .. (even notepad is fine)

and add below line :

```
<add path="*.asp" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" validate="True"/>
```

under below XPath:

`configuration/system.web/httpHandlers`

replace the existing one!

Add below line:

```
<add extension=".asp" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
```

under below XPath:

```
/configuration/system.web/compilation/buildProviders
```

Worked like gem for me :)